# Retry Attempt without data loss when sink side solr is down during runtime

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{
"name": "t1",
"config": {
"tasks.max": "1",
"value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
"value.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
"key.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
"key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
"connector.class": "com.github.jcustenborder.kafka.connect.solr.HttpSolrSinkConnector",
"topics": "TRAN",
"solr.queue.size": "100",
"solr.commit.within": "10",
"solr.url": "http://192.168.2.221:27052/solr/TRAN",
"errors.retry.delay.max.ms":"5000",
"errors.retry.timeout":"600000",
"errors.tolerance":"all",
"errors.log.enable":"true",
"errors.log.include.messages":"false",
"errors.deadletterqueue.topic.name":"DEAD_TRAN",
"errors.deadletterqueue.topic.replication.factor":"1",
"retry.backoff.ms":"1000",
"reconnect.backoff.ms":"5000",
"reconnect.backoff.max.ms":"600000"
}
}' http://localhost:8083/connectors
```

Need to retry ( without any data loss) based on count from connector config if solr server is down during runtime.

In my case, Its working perfectly whenboth connector and solr are in running state [Active].
But while only solr server is down, there is no retry process until my data passed to the solr leads to data loss..

Error Information shown below
[image]

Connector Config from the Kafka Connect Log

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've just checked the `SinkTask` implementation of [that specific connector](https://github.com/jcustenborder/kafka-connect-solr/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/jcustenborder/kafka/connect/solr/SolrSinkTask.java) and it does throw a `RetriableException` in the `put()` method.

In theory, and according to your connector configuration, it should block for 10 minutes (`"errors.retry.timeout" : "600000"`). If your SolR instance recover within the 10 minutes there shouldn't be any problem in terms of data loss.

If you want to fully block your connector until solR is up on his feet, have you tried to set `"errors.retry.timeout" : "-1"`?

As per the [documentation](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/configuration/connect/sink-connect-configs.html#errors.retry.timeout) of `errors.retry.timeout`:

> The maximum duration in milliseconds that a failed operation will be
> reattempted. The default is 0, which means no retries will be
> attempted. Use -1 for infinite retries.

PS: IMHO this might lead to a deadlock situation if for some reason a single message is permanently failing its sink operation (i.e: if the sink is rejecting the operation).

Comment: `Sample Config
"config": {
 "tasks.max": "1",
 "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
 "value.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
 "key.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
 "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
 "connector.class": "com.github.jcustenborder.kafka.connect.solr.HttpSolrSinkConnector",
 "topics": "TRAN",
 "solr.queue.size": "100",
 "solr.commit.within": "10",
 "solr.url": "http://192.168.2.221:27052/solr/TRAN",
 "errors.retry.delay.max.ms":"5000",
 "errors.retry.timeout":"-1",
 "errors.tolerance":"all"
}`

Comment: - I have tried "errors.retry.timeout" : "-1" but still same result
- In brief, There will be 4 steps for producing data into solr
- Step 1 -> Conversion Process [JsonConverter]
- Step 2 -> Transformation Process [Transformation]
- Step 3 -> Put() [Data to Solr]

Comment: - If any errors occured in between step 1 and 2, then task will be failed and it can also be skipped with tolerance property and here only errors.retry.timeout will works.
- In Step 3, there is no any retry attempt logs in the kafka connect console and i have restarted the solr instance next after getting the solr connection refused error...but still data is not moved solr.
- Retry attempt should be implement in kafka-connect-solar
- Confluent side should verify the basic things before going to suggest[Highly disappointed]

Comment: Can you confirm which exceptions you get on the connector log when your SolR instance is down? If your `put()` is failing and returning `RetriableException`, with this `errors.retry.timeout=-1` it will retry forever and will tell the Connect framework not to commit offsets because the downstream sink operation is failing.